# custom annotation to print a text in annotated method

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I have an annotation called `PrintSomething`

And I have it below:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface PrintSomething {
    String value() default "";
}
```

And What I want is to print whatever the value I put in annotation, I want to print that value in every method call. Like:

```
public class SomeObject {
    private int someStuff;

    @PrintSomething("i want this string to be printed")
    public shouldPrintSomething() {
        // I want whatever this code is here to run afterwards
        this.someStuff = 2;
    }
}
```

And when I call, I want to do:

```
SomeObject someObject = new SomeObject();
someObject.shouldPrintSomething();
```

I want to see *i want this string to be printed* to be printed first, and then having the field of the object set to *2*.

I wasn't able achieve it, is that possible to achieve such thing. I wasn't able to do it.

Comment: Show your annotation processor.

Comment: See if [this article](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaAnnotations/article.html) is of any help.